# Bat | Работа с текстовым документом

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Всем привет, у меня возникли некоторые трудности в задаче:

> Записывать в файл logcopy.txt имя каждого копируемого файла и
> результат выполнения операции для него. Файл logcopy.txt должен быть
> примерно таким:
> Успешно: а.txt
> Ошибка : b.txt

Как это можно реализовать? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: For /F. Внутри Copy и If Errorlevel.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо)